# The TAP website does not recognise the voucher they sent me and the phone goes dead when I try to ring

Tags: refunds, tap-portugal, vouchers

Having received a voucher which is valid for 24 months from TAP for a cancelled flight in June, I am now totally unable to reach them by phone or book an alternative flight through the website. Despite copying and pasting the voucher code, it says it is not a valid code.

Has anyone had the same problem? If so, how did you tackle it?

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to confuse letters and numbers in the code, like O and 0, and l and 1. I don't know this code, but sometimes they can be ambiguous.

Comment: Great suggestion, have now tried, but no better sadly. Thank you though

Comment: I had to deal with TAP Air over the summer to get a refund for a flight and I ended up direct messaging their Twitter support–phone lines didn't pick up and support form online replied after a couple months saying I had the wrong department (huh). The most recent exchange in September took them *7* days to reply. However, I did get my refund (after many months of back and forth). If you cannot reach them another way, and it's not urgent, consider this approach. @tapairportugal is the twitter account.

Comment: So they responded to the twitter contact, but my query hasn't moved forwards yet, will update as we continue

Comment: Seriously, twitter is AMAZING for getting in touch with airlines.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you’re inputting the voucher code correctly? Sometimes ‘copy & paste’ isn’t accurate eg I’ve had it pick up an extra space at the end without me realising

Comment: So it turns out that because I booked through GoToGate which is based in Sweden the voucher is in Swedish Kroner, and I therefore need to book on the Swedish website which is flytap.com/en-se/

Comment: @Traveller Oh, how I wish website designers would trim whitespace from the start/end of fields!  I've been burned by such errant spaces many times.

Comment: @Barbara Jemec Great you’ve solved your problem, you can post your comment as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 1):

In my recent experience speaking with TAP (due to their buggy website and Portugal’s confusing and confused COVID rules), some combinations of menu options will lead to a couple minutes on hold, followed by a hang-up.

My suggestion is to try a different menu combination that is reasonable related (I.e. don’t pick Miles & Go for a booking inquiry)- that worked for me more than once (after some time on hold) and unfailing led to a very polite and helpful human being with good English skills.

I used Skype out to minimize the cost of calling +212 Portugal from outside Europe (North America and Africa).

Comment: OP had first bought from the Swedish site and needed to use that site to redeem the voucher

Comment: Sure, just addressing the issue of getting ahold of the TAP folks on the phone.